# Chrome Extension Manifest matches not working for clicking into that url

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have the following manifest

```
{
  "manifest_version":2,
  "name": "HelloWorld",
  "version": "0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://www.mywebsite.com/"
      ],
      "js": ["home.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]
}
```

It works perfectly when I enter `www.mywebsite.com` through browser url bar. But when I route to the same url `www.mywebsite.com` through hyperlinks in another url, the script does not trigger. Why is that? I do not see this in

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it's not a bad pattern because it's got the forward slash in the end of the pattern to match a specific path. And as I said, it works perfectly when I url-bar into my website.

Comment: The pattern matches only the root path so if the site is AJAX-driven and you visit a subpath first, the content script won't match, then the site will fake navigation to the root path without actually fetching the page from server, but content scripts are loaded only on full load of a page, not on AJAX navigation. Note, depending on what you actually do in your content script, this may apply to any combination of URLs, not just root.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what happened... AJAX navigation. How can I ever match AJAX navigation though? What I do in the script are `window.location.replace("www...xx")` in root path, and also did `querySelector('button#some-id").click()` in other pathes

Comment: Weird thing though, that the 'hashchange' event is not fired when I click around different pathes in the same domain. Is it still AJAX navigation if 'hashchange' doesn't fire?

Comment: History API doesn't have to change the hash part of the URL, the entire path can be dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out a temporary method, you can do

```
<some_dom_object>.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // do the thing you want happen.
})
```

on that "button element" or "anchor element" or whatever that you clicked to that website, so the code will get executed also when you "click" to the url.

Comment: If this works for you, the problem must be in the content script code, not in manifest, but you didn't show it...